# Realtime microphone sound level monitoring

Tags: ios, iphone, microphone

I'm trying to access sound volume data from the microphone in realtime. I've tried AVAudioPlayer but it only monitors sounds from a source like an mp3 and not from a microphone. I've also tried The SpeakHere app but it's proving to be much tougher to understand with all the Objective C++ syntax (i'm a newbie). Is there another class similiar to the one in SpeakHere but written only in Objective C?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[sc_listener](https://github.com/stephencelis/sc_listener) is deprecated. The correct answer today is to use [`AVAudioRecorder`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html). [This tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20090823020843/http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-detecting-when-a-user-blows-into-the-mic/) explains how to use it.

---

Answer (score 6):

Erik's answer is correct. Here is a reusable implementation using this method as a recognizer/delegate.

https://github.com/picciano/iOS-Audio-Recoginzer

Comment: can we get the decibel(dB SPL) value of microphone, with your project?

Comment: It includes the power levels, but I've read too many conflicting theories on exactly how to calculate the dB levels. I choose to leave that exercise to the reader. :)

Comment: Can [AVAudioSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW42)