# iOS xcode microphone volume detection?

Tags: ios, xcode, volume, microphone, ios-frameworks

What frameworks are required to detect how loud someone is talking into a microphone... Also, can anyone tell me what to search for in the documentation or google so I can create some code... What line of code would be commonly used when detecting volume levels of noise through the microphone? Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This seems to be a duplicate of:

[Realtime microphone sound level monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155010/realtime-microphone-sound-level-monitoring)

However, that question is old and the accepted answer links to a [deprecated library](https://github.com/stephencelis/sc_listener). They now recommend that you instead use [`AVAudioRecorder`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html). They suggest [this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20090823020843/http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-detecting-when-a-user-blows-into-the-mic/) and it seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thankyou!!!! Just what I was looking for! "AVAudioRecorder" is the type of think I was asking for that I can google! Thanks again!!!!!

Comment: @Albert You're welcome. I see that you haven't accepted any answers. You do so by clicking on the green check mark right next to the answer that helped you the most. This lets people know what answer is correct and you and the answerer earns reputation. You can (and should) also upvote answers (and questions) that you like. Just click the up arrow next to the post.